# onChange input in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I am building webapp using React and [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) library. I would like to create form where change of some field triggers some event. So I need pass custom `onChange`

However, since v7.0 I can't use `onChange` because `register` uses its own `onChange`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const MyForm = () => {

  const form = useForm()
  const onChangeFirst = value => console.log('First:', value)
  const onChangeSecond = value => console.log('Second:', value)

  return (
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(vals => null)}>
      <input {...register('first')} />
      <input {...register('second')} />
    </form> 
  )

}
```

How can I pass `onChangeFirst` to `first` input and `onChangeSecond` to `second` input?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways to trigger `onChange` while input change.

1/ With [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) component (recommend)

```
const onChangeFirst = value => console.log('First:', value)

<Controller
  control={control}
  name="first"
  render={({field}) => (
    <input {...field} onChange={e => {
      onChangeFirst(field.value);
      field.onChange(e);
    }} />
  )}
/>
```

2/ With [useWatch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch) hook

```
 const second = useWatch({
    control,
    name: 'second'
 });

 useEffect(() => {
   console.log('Second:', second)
 }, [second])
```

Answer (score 2):

With [watch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch):

```
const { register, watch } = useForm()
const first = watch("first")

useEffect(() => {
    // do something with first
}, [first])

…

<input {...register('first')} />
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as per the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register):

```js
import React from "react";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";

const MyForm = () => {
    const form = useForm();

    return <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(values => console.log(values))}>
        <input {...form.register('first', {onChange: e => console.log(e.target.value)})}/>
        <input {...form.register('second', {onChange: e => console.log(e.target.value)})}/>
    </form>
}
```

Before I saw that the above was possible, I posted this solution which works without using a Controller component (I left it here because it contains information that might be useful to someone):

```js
import React, {forwardRef} from "react";
import {FormProvider, useForm, useFormContext} from "react-hook-form";

const Input = forwardRef({itemKey, handleChange, ...rest}), ref => {
    const {register} = useFormContext();
    const reg = register(itemKey);
    const handleChangeWrapped = e => {
        reg.onChange(e);
        handleChange?.(e.target.value);
    }

    return <input ref={ref} {...rest} {...reg} onChange={handleChangeWrapped}/>
});

const MyForm = () => {
    const form = useForm();

    return <FormProvider {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(values => console.log(values))}>
            <Input itemKey={'first'} handleChange={value => console.log(value)}/>
            <Input itemKey={'second'} handleChange={value => console.log(value)}/>
        </form>
    </FormProvider>
}
```